# Installing Zend Framework on Denwer

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to install zend framework on Denwer (webserver), but after doing the whole stuff when I am running the zf.bat create project myproject command I get the following error message:

The procedure entry point php_getopt could not be located in the dynamic link php5ts.dll

Does this mean that ZF installation has not been done properly? 
How can I overcome this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If no project structure or files were created, then it did not succeed at all.

To solve this problem, upgrade PHP to version 5.3.0 as the getopt function did not exist on Windows until 5.3.0.  Once upgraded you should be able to use Zend Tool to create projects/controllers/models etc.